# REGEX - Inserting things between html comment pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to create some js to lazy loading in html files. So I have to create the patterns inside html comments and than inject the script tags for js files. Something like [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject), but my own way.

Here's html comment examples:

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
<!--endinject-->
```

I want to to identify comment patterns and inject the script tag inside then and it should do something like:

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
<script src="app/start.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/some.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/content.module.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->
```

Here's what I have tried till now with RegEx:

```
/(<!--(inject:?([\w]*?)?:?([\w]*?)?)-->)(<!--endinject-->)*?/gm
```

It will select only the first "inject" comment.

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
```

PS.: I'm still newbie in RegEx.

Thanks!

Comment: if your regex was working before. you can try this. /(<!--(inject:?([\w]*?)?:?([\w]*?)?)-->).*(<!--endinject-->)*?/gm . moreover please add more code to understand how you are fetching comments

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question? I cannot parse your first sentence, "I'm trying to create some js to lazy loading in html files."

Comment: Basically, I want to identify the pattern in the comments and inject the script tag between both comments.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/ for more practice in regexp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries (thanks to @Tomalak), I found the solution.

Given the current html comment with script tags:

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
<script src="app/start.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/some.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/content.module.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->
```

I did this to match 3 groups:

```
/(<!--(inject:?(\w*?):?(\w*?)?)-->)([\s\S]*?)(<!--endinject-->)/g
```

where group 1 is:

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
```

Group 2 is:

```
<script src="app/start.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/some.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/content.module.js"></script>
```

And group 3 is:

```
<!--endinject-->
```

With this 3 matches I can detect the comment patterns and append other script tags in group 2. This is what I wanted.

Here's the link to test: http://regexr.com/3cibb

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Saying "thanks" works by upvoting (and possibly accepting) the answers that helped you. Not repaying the people that helped you (and instead posting your own version of the same answer) is rude. Please don't be rude.

Comment: Also, your regex contains at least three errors. This expression could never actually have worked.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't want to be rude. What's wrong in this regex? I didn't find errors.

Comment: Also...Could you edit your question? Than I can accept it.

Comment: No, scratch that, the expression is all-right. My mistake. You could do it in a simpler fashion though, some parts of your regex are redundant. `(<!--inject:?(\w*?):?(\w*?)-->)([\s\S]*?)(<!--endinject-->)`

Comment: Nice! Thanks again @Tomalak!

Answer (score 1):

When applied to

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
<script src="app/start.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/some.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/content.module.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->
```

this

```
(<!--inject:(\w+):(\w+)-->(?:(?!<!--endinject-->)[\s\S])*)(?=<!--endinject-->)
```

matches:

Group 1:

```
<!--inject:module:js-->
<script src="app/start.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/some.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/content.module.js"></script>
```

groups 2 and 3 contain `module` and `js`, respectively.

You could go ahead and replace any matches with `$1\n<script src="another/script.js"></script>\n`.

This would retain the comment structure and therefore could be used multiple times in a row on the same input.